# Asymptotics of a quadratic form with growing vector / matrix dimensions

Tags: asymptotics

Let $\ {\bf x}_n=\big\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\big\}$ be a vector of random variables with ${\bf m}_n=\big\{\mu_1,\mu_2,...,\mu_n\big\}$ and $\ n^{1/2}({\bf x}_n-{\bf m}_n)\rightarrow N(0,\Omega_n)$ 
Assuming that $ \Omega_n^{-1}$ is well-defined, I am interested in a probability limit such as the following (which I guess converges to 1 but I could be wrong):
$$
plim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \ ({\bf x}_n-{\bf m}_n)'\Omega_n^{-1}({\bf x}_n-{\bf m}_n)
$$
How can one tackle questions like these?

Answer (score 0):

It will converge to 1 in probability, since $n(x_n-m_n)'\Omega_n^{-1}(x_n-m_n)\approx \chi^2_n$ and $\chi^2_n/n$ converges to 1 in probability.

Comment: thanks for your response but I am not sure that your approach is right. The potential problem is that $x_n$ becomes normal in the limit and because the size of $x_n$ and $\Omega_n$ increases with the sample size, sum of the terms that we often ignore in deriving asymptotic Chi-square distribution may add up to a nonzero element.

Comment: @user41838 I think that as long as $\Omega_n$ is fixed with respect to $n$, my approach would be correct. If the minmum and maximum eigenvalues of $\Omega_n$ are not bounded in asymptotic sense, you may need to change the notation, $n^{1/2}(x_n-m_n) \rightarrow N(0,\Omega_n)$.